# What is wrong with my brakes and rotors?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, control-arm

I've replaced my rotors and brakes 3 times in the past 18 months. A mechanic this last time said the lower control arm needed replacing so I did. Not even 8 moths have gone by, 4000 miles and I'm already having the same issues again. I don't know why or how. Can someone explain why?

Comment: What issue are you having?  Why do they need replacing?

Comment: What kind of vehicle? How old is it? What kind of driving? _I wonder if this is Lewis Hamilton hiding behind internet anonymity..._ :)

Comment: Please edit your question and add pertinent details.  About all I can say at this point is that either you have an incompetent mechanic or you have something wrong with your car other than just the brakes.

Comment: Guessing warped rotors the wobble wobble wobble?

Comment: If warp is the issue take a look at your driving style. I had the same issue for 3 years multiple rotors, some changed by mechanic, some myself. Then I got dogs that loved to drive, ended up retraining me to brake earlier and lighter. Been 2 years on last rotors still no issues. That's only thing that changed. Interestingly only one vehicle was susceptible to my heavy braking and warping.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While driving, does the car feel like it wants to slow down sooner after releasing  gas pedal? When stopped, after releasing the brake pedal, does the car want to stay in place or creep ahead without using the gas pedal? The car wanting to stay in place and slowing down sooner after releasing the gas pedal suggests dragging brakes/poor brake service. If vehicle drives normally, coasts easily when releasing gas pedal at speed, creeps on flat ground after releasing the brake pedal/light acceleration, this shop may be creating unethical repairs and your lack of familiarity of cars in general.